# Python: line 26 str object is not callable after a certain input

Tags: python, json, string, object, debugging

so this is a program that read a json file and just translates any input to a known English word and tries it's best to get a close match from the json file.

However when i input for example:
Animal then hello, the program crashes, if i spam hello it does not crash, if i input hello then animal it does not crash, it crashes only when i input hello then animal but not vise versa.

If i input animal alone it works fine aswell.
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 26, in 
    translations=trans(word)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import json
import difflib

data = json.load(open("data .json"))
print("Please note the commands can be entered in small or capital letters as you like")

def trans(w):
  w= w.lower()
  if w in data:
    return data[w]
  else:
    bestMatch= difflib.get_close_matches(w,data.keys())
    for match in bestMatch:
      match=match.capitalize()
      command=input("Did you mean "+match+" Y for yes and N for no and -1 to go back\n")
      command=command.lower()
      if command=='y':
        return trans(match)
      elif command=='-1':
        return ""
    return "The word does not exist"

word=input("Enter a word or -1 to exit\n")

while word != "-1":
  translations=trans(word)
  if type(translations)==str:
    print("Definition: ")
  if len(translations)==1:
    print(translations[0])
  else:
    for trans in translations:
      print(trans)
  word=input("Enter a word or -1 to exit\n")
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the content of `data.json` please? This would make this question a MCVE.

Comment: You can't have `trans` as both the name of a function, and the name of a variable (used in that very last `for` loop).  The times when your code did work are cases where that `for` loop was never executed, and therefore `trans` was never reassigned.